# Installing Aqueduct for a dart server

Tags: server, dart, aqueduct

I'm trying to build a server using Dart/Aqueduct.
But when i try to set things up i get following error after i type "pub global activate aqueduct" in my command line:

```html
../../runtime/vm/raw_object.cc: 283: error: unreachable code
Dumping native stack trace for thread 33
  [0x000000000090efc3] dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace()
  [0x000000000090efc3] dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace()
  [0x000000000068d1a1] dart::DynamicAssertionHelper::Fail(char const*, ...)
  [0x00000000009122a0] dart::RawObject::VisitPointers(dart::ObjectPointerVisitor*)
  [0x0000000000951b18] dart::Scavenger::ProcessToSpace(dart::ScavengerVisitor*)
  [0x000000000095212d] dart::Scavenger::Scavenge(bool)
  [0x0000000000768609] dart::Heap::CollectNewSpaceGarbage(dart::Thread*, dart::Heap::ApiCallbacks, dart::Heap::GCReason)
  [0x0000000000767692] dart::Heap::AllocateNew(long)
  [0x00000000007e715e] dart::Object::Allocate(long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
  [0x00000000007ea9e6] dart::Array::New(long, dart::Heap::Space)
  [0x00000000009bd031] dart::DRT_AllocateArray(dart::NativeArguments)
  [0x00007f77e26a061b] [Stub] CallToRuntime
  [0x00007f77e26a16e2] [Stub] AllocateArray
```

I had to terminate the execution because it got stuck.

it also gets stuck using "pub global activate stagehand" so i guess the problem is with "pub global activate ... "

Hope someone has an idea and can help me.
Thanks in advance

after running "pub global activate -v aqueduct"

```html
 FINE: Pub 1.24.0-dev.6.4
MSG : Resolving dependencies...
SLVR: Solving dependencies:
    | - aqueduct any from hosted (aqueduct)
IO  : Get versions from https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/aqueduct.
FINE: HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/aqueduct
    | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
    | X-Pub-OS: linux
    | X-Pub-Command: global activate
    | X-Pub-Session-ID: 55613A99-D375-47A9-9088-AAB0A68A7438
    | user-agent: Dart pub 1.24.0-dev.6.4
FINE: HTTP response 200 OK for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/aqueduct
    | took 0:00:00.644556
    | date: Sat, 03 Jun 2017 19:20:30 GMT
    | transfer-encoding: chunked
    | via: 1.1 google
    | content-type: application/json
    | x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    | x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    | x-content-type-options: nosniff
    | server: nginx
SLVR: * start at root
IO  : Get versions from https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/stack_trace.
FINE: HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/stack_trace
    | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
    | X-Pub-OS: linux
    | X-Pub-Command: global activate
    | X-Pub-Session-ID: 55613A99-D375-47A9-9088-AAB0A68A7438
    | user-agent: Dart pub 1.24.0-dev.6.4
FINE: HTTP response 200 OK for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/stack_trace
    | took 0:00:00.267917
    | date: Sat, 03 Jun 2017 19:20:30 GMT
    | transfer-encoding: chunked
    | via: 1.1 google
    | content-type: application/json
    | x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    | x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    | x-content-type-options: nosniff
    | server: nginx
SLVR: Could not get versions for stack_trace from hosted:
    | Connection closed while receiving data
    |
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 337                                      BoundHostedSource._throwFriendlyError
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 139                                      BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
    | package:pub/src/source.dart 165                                             BoundSource.getVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 230                              SolverCache.getVersions.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/http.dart 227                                               withDependencyType
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 229                              SolverCache.getVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 121                    UnselectedPackageQueue._getNumVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 50                     UnselectedPackageQueue.add
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 68                            VersionSelection.select.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.forEach
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 61                            VersionSelection.select
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 308                         BacktrackingSolver._solve.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.doWhile
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 276                         BacktrackingSolver._solve
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 176                         BacktrackingSolver.solve
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 41                               resolveVersions.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/log.dart 409                                                progress
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 39                               resolveVersions
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 166                                    GlobalPackages._installInCache
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 116                                    GlobalPackages.activateHosted
    | package:pub/src/command/global_activate.dart 91                             GlobalActivateCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 194                                        CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168                                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 99                                               captureErrors.<fn>
    | package:stack_trace                                                         Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 114                                              captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168                                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 117                                     PubCommandRunner.run
    | /tmp/tmp5krbLf/dart-1.24.0-dev.6.4/dart/third_party/pkg/pub/bin/pub.dart 8  main
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _Completer.completeError
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 152                                      BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _asyncErrorWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 128                                      BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
    | package:pub/src/source.dart 165                                             BoundSource.getVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 230                              SolverCache.getVersions.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/http.dart 227                                               withDependencyType
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 229                              SolverCache.getVersions
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 203                              SolverCache.getVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 121                    UnselectedPackageQueue._getNumVersions
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 115                    UnselectedPackageQueue._getNumVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 50                     UnselectedPackageQueue.add
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 44                     UnselectedPackageQueue.add
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 68                            VersionSelection.select.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 61                            VersionSelection.select.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.forEach
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 61                            VersionSelection.select
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.forEach
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 61                            VersionSelection.select
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _asyncThenWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 53                            VersionSelection.select
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 308                         BacktrackingSolver._solve.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _asyncThenWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 276                         BacktrackingSolver._solve.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.doWhile
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 276                         BacktrackingSolver._solve
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.doWhile
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 276                         BacktrackingSolver._solve
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 274                         BacktrackingSolver._solve
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 176                         BacktrackingSolver.solve
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _asyncThenWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 157                         BacktrackingSolver.solve
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 41                               resolveVersions.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/log.dart 409                                                progress
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 39                               resolveVersions
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 166                                    GlobalPackages._installInCache
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 160                                    GlobalPackages._installInCache
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 116                                    GlobalPackages.activateHosted
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 114                                    GlobalPackages.activateHosted
    | package:pub/src/command/global_activate.dart 91                             GlobalActivateCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 194                                        CommandRunner.runCommand
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 142                                        CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168                                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 99                                               captureErrors.<fn>
    | package:stack_trace                                                         Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 114                                              captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168                                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand
SLVR: Could not get versions for stack_trace from hosted:
    | Connection closed while receiving data
    |
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 337                                      BoundHostedSource._throwFriendlyError
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 139                                      BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
    | package:pub/src/source.dart 165                                             BoundSource.getVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 230                              SolverCache.getVersions.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/http.dart 227                                               withDependencyType
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 229                              SolverCache.getVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 121                    UnselectedPackageQueue._getNumVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 50                     UnselectedPackageQueue.add
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 68                            VersionSelection.select.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.forEach
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 61                            VersionSelection.select
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 308                         BacktrackingSolver._solve.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.doWhile
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 276                         BacktrackingSolver._solve
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 176                         BacktrackingSolver.solve
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 41                               resolveVersions.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/log.dart 409                                                progress
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 39                               resolveVersions
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 166                                    GlobalPackages._installInCache
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 116                                    GlobalPackages.activateHosted
    | package:pub/src/command/global_activate.dart 91                             GlobalActivateCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 194                                        CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168                                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 99                                               captureErrors.<fn>
    | package:stack_trace                                                         Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 114                                              captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168                                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 117                                     PubCommandRunner.run
    | /tmp/tmp5krbLf/dart-1.24.0-dev.6.4/dart/third_party/pkg/pub/bin/pub.dart 8  main
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _Completer.completeError
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 152                                      BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _asyncErrorWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 128                                      BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
    | package:pub/src/source.dart 165                                             BoundSource.getVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 230                              SolverCache.getVersions.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/http.dart 227                                               withDependencyType
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 229                              SolverCache.getVersions
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 203                              SolverCache.getVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 121                    UnselectedPackageQueue._getNumVersions
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 115                    UnselectedPackageQueue._getNumVersions
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 50                     UnselectedPackageQueue.add
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/unselected_package_queue.dart 44                     UnselectedPackageQueue.add
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 68                            VersionSelection.select.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 61                            VersionSelection.select.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.forEach
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 61                            VersionSelection.select
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.forEach
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 61                            VersionSelection.select
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _asyncThenWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_selection.dart 53                            VersionSelection.select
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 308                         BacktrackingSolver._solve.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _asyncThenWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 276                         BacktrackingSolver._solve.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.doWhile
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 276                         BacktrackingSolver._solve
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  Future.doWhile
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 276                         BacktrackingSolver._solve
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 274                         BacktrackingSolver._solve
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 176                         BacktrackingSolver.solve
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  _asyncThenWrapperHelper
    | package:pub/src/solver/backtracking_solver.dart 157                         BacktrackingSolver.solve
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 41                               resolveVersions.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/log.dart 409                                                progress
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 39                               resolveVersions
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 166                                    GlobalPackages._installInCache
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 160                                    GlobalPackages._installInCache
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 116                                    GlobalPackages.activateHosted
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 114                                    GlobalPackages.activateHosted
    | package:pub/src/command/global_activate.dart 91                             GlobalActivateCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 194                                        CommandRunner.runCommand
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.microtask
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 142                                        CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168                                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                  new Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 99                                               captureErrors.<fn>
    | package:stack_trace                                                         Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 114                                              captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168                                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand
IO  : Get versions from https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/pub_semver.
FINE: HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/pub_semver
    | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
    | X-Pub-OS: linux
    | X-Pub-Command: global activate
    | X-Pub-Session-ID: 55613A99-D375-47A9-9088-AAB0A68A7438
    | user-agent: Dart pub 1.24.0-dev.6.4
FINE: HTTP response 200 OK for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/pub_semver
    | took 0:00:00.280514
    | date: Sat, 03 Jun 2017 19:24:31 GMT
    | transfer-encoding: chunked
    | via: 1.1 google
    | content-type: application/json
    | x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    | x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    | x-content-type-options: nosniff
    | server: nginx
IO  : Get versions from https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/safe_config.
FINE: HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/safe_config
    | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
    | X-Pub-OS: linux
    | X-Pub-Command: global activate
    | X-Pub-Session-ID: 55613A99-D375-47A9-9088-AAB0A68A7438
    | user-agent: Dart pub 1.24.0-dev.6.4
FINE: HTTP response 200 OK for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/safe_config
    | took 0:00:00.157651
    | date: Sat, 03 Jun 2017 19:24:31 GMT
    | transfer-encoding: chunked
    | via: 1.1 google
    | content-type: application/json
    | x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    | x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    | x-content-type-options: nosniff
    | server: nginx
```

after that it got stuck.
Don't really know what to do with this information tbh.

Comment: Can you try running it as 'pub global activate -v aqueduct'? It'll tell you where pub is failing.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. Missed the notification.

Comment: It appears it is failing to fetch a dependency because of a prematurely closed HTTP connection. I noticed you are running a dev version of Dart, which may not be stable. Have you tried installing 1.23.0?

Comment: Yes I've tried both, the stable and the Dev version. Same problem with both versions